# How do we account for gravity affecting the actual measurement of time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, time

Let's suppose we are in Newtonian Mechanics, and we have a clock, say a mechanical stop watch. Then, it is that the gears of the stopwatch is affected by gravity, and hence the time ticks faster at some time than other. For example, if we are on the earth, and hold the stop watch vertically w.r.t ground, I would imagine the time ticks faster when the clock is moving from 12 o clock to 6 o clock, than from 6 o clock to 12 o clock. Since in the second case, the clock would be moving against gravity than with it.

So, it would seem to me that the presence of gravity itself makes my clock bad.

In all treatments I haven't seen this phenomena being discussed, so, how would one justify they can ignore this effect? If it's not actually trivial, is there any attempt to describe the deviation due to it?

Comment: Gravity does have an effect on the accuracy of mechanical watches, certainly more than e.g. gravitational time dilation on Earth. In fact I believe watches are tested in different orientations because the gravity-induced accuracy penalty also depends on the orientation (i.e. the direction of gravity relative to the watch). This is really more about watchmaking than physics, [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: I was thinking more like comparison of magnitude time dilation due to relativity and time discrepancy due to gravity breaking my clock @Puk

Comment: Depending on orientation, a mechanical watch might gain or lose on the order of 1 s/day, or 10 μs/s. Gravitational time dilation on the surface of the Earth is about 600 ps/s.

Comment: How did you come up with these estimates? Very fascinating o_o @Puk

Comment: I know from experience that the accuracy variation of mechanical watches is usually on the order of 1 s/day. [Gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation) can be estimated using the [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric).

Comment: I don't understand why you would think that gravity would have any impact on the gears.  The gears are round so have an even gravitational  resistance as they turn in circles.

Comment: I mean, the hour hand, not the gears @foolishmuse

Comment: I changed the tags on this question because "suppose we are in Newtonian Mechanics"

Comment: The effect is more direct for pendulum clocks, because the period of oscillation of a pendulum increases when $g$ decreases. A naive experimentalist would conclude that time ticks slower when we increase the altitude, the opposite of stated by GR:)

Comment: Are you trying to talk about gravitational time dilation i.e. GR, or are you trying to talk about mechanical clocks? The GR correction has nothing to do with the specific details of the clocks. Mechanical clocks can be designed, say, by horizontal alignment so that the gravitational effects are cancelled out. If you want the clock hands vertical and still want precision, the clock hands are easily pivot balanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In all treatments I haven't seen this phenomena being discussed, so, how would one justify they can ignore this effect?

It is rather straightforward to make such justifications. There are two basic approaches: theoretical and experimental

For the theoretical approach, first, you assume that the effect of concern cannot be ignored. Then you calculate how big of an effect it would have on your clock. Then you compare it to other sources of error. If it is substantially smaller than the other sources of error then it can be ignored.

For the experimental approach, first you build six clocks. Then you operate three in an environment where they are subject to the effect of concern and you operate the other three in an environment where they are not subject to the effect of concern. Then you compare them, if the variation within each group is substantially larger than the variation between groups then it can be ignored.

The experimental approach is more convincing, but the comparison can be complicated by the fact that often changing the effect of concern also requires changing other potentially confounding effects. As a result often a hybrid approach is used. The effect of concern is varied experimentally, and other confounding effects are accounted for theoretically.

We don’t use mechanical clocks for precision metrology, so that is not too important in this context. We use atomic clocks. For atomic clocks we have the hybrid approach. The GPS satellites have atomic clocks, and are in free fall, so they have no g-forces. But they are subject to both special and general relativistic effects, as well as the temperature aboard the satellite. Those effects are compensated for theoretically and then there is no measurable remaining effect due to the g-forces.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanical clocks use a process with fixed frequency to regulate the motion of the hands. This can be done either by having an electric motor set to rotate at a fixed rate driving a simple gear system, or by keeping the works of the clock under continuous tension (using springs or a weight) and releasing the works to move a fixed angular distance before arresting the motion, periodically with fixed frequency, which is what produces the characteristic ticking sound.